# classification of documents considering the order of words

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to classify a list of documents. I'm using CountVectorizer and TfidfVectorizer to vectorize the documents before the classification. The results are good but I think that they could be better if we will consider not only the existence of specific words in the document but also the order of these words. I know that it is possible to consider also pairs and triples of words but I'm looking for something more inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, but bag of words approaches work quite well on a wide range of text datasets. You've already thought of bi-grams or tri-grams. Let's say you had 10-grams. You have information about the order of your words, but it turns out there are rarely more than one instance of each 10-gram, so there would be few examples for your classification model to learn from. You could try some other custom feature engineering based on the text, but it would be a good amount of work that rarely help much. There are other successful approaches in Natural Language Processing, especially in the last few years, but they usually focus on more than word ordering.

Comment: the documents I'm working with are forms and not free text. certain words can appear at the beginning of the document or at the end. it should change the classification accordingly. the question is: is there an algorithm that can take this into consideration? unfortunately, the 10-gram approach will not help me